# how does REST web service work

Tags: java, rest

I have a rest web service as below:

```
@GET
@Path("/getPersonDetails/{personId}/{validDate}")
@Produces("application/xml")
  public PersonDetail getPersonDetails(@PathParam("personId") final String personId,@PathParam("validDate") String validDate) {

    PersonDetail p = new PersonDetail;

    //all the processing to set data into object p

    return p;
}
```

When called from the browser with appropriate parameters, this service is returning the object as an xml as expected.

However, how does it work internally ?

From where does the tags in the xml get set ?

Is it from

1) the names of the local variables inside the service method

2) the names of class properties in the class

3) the name of the class itself

What happens between the method returning the object and it appearing on browser as XML ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You could probably answer much of this question yourself by playing around with renaming fields and methods of your application.

Comment: And could probably answer a lot more of it by scanning the traffic (if on Windows run it through fiddler, otherwise wireshark or similar). It's also well-worth reading RFC2616 and Fielding's dissertation, if you want to know how REST works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML structure is generated by the [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding). It creates XML tags based on class fields. Of course, this process can be customised. See Lars Vogels [tutorial on JAXB](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html) for an example of how to achieve this.

After the `getPersonDetails()` method returns, the JAX-RS runtime invokes the JAXB [`Marshaller`](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/jaxb20-pr/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) turns the return value of the method into an XML structure, which gets written back to your web browser.